# Use of negative present participle

Tags: relative-clauses, present-participles

I'm in trouble to compare the following two sentences in view of flow. The first one uses **negative present participle** (which is my favorite):

> all subsystems not belonging to the currently-active configuration
>   should have been deactivated.

But I'm wondering whether this sentence sounds awkward or not.

The second one is the same sentence rewritten with a **relative clause**:

> all subsystems which don't belong to the currently-active
>   configuration should have been deactivated.

I'm so thankful if a native speaker give me some advice about the better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both seem grammatically correct, but I would say that the first is better because it is less clunky.